# Looking for a Sci-fi Harry Potter fanfiction with Harry in the future

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Harry is in the future and has magic, but doesn't have a wand. Voldemort is alive and was being experimented on. The magic population was wiped out by either the Muggles or Voldemort. The Muggles experimented on him and created some soldiers based on his DNA or something. A descendant of Severus Snape is in the story. Harry finally finds a wand and some other wizard stuff some time in the future of the fic. I think it might be a *Firefly* crossover, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Do you remember when are where you read this? If it was on a specific website it may help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/2857962/1/Browncoat-Green-Eyes has some matches, but no Voldemort experiments that I can find with a quick search. Harry is brought back by Antonio Wetherby, scion of the Weasly family, at the bequest of the Alliance.